# SQL server campo xml filtrar por um campo com namespace

Tags: sql, xml

eu tentei via seq filtrar um registro que tinha um campo xml, com o esse xml abaixo:

```
    <ns1:Prod xmlns:ns1="uri">  
  <ns1:ProductID>316</ns1:ProductID>  
  <ns1:Name>Blade</ns1:Name>  
</ns1:Prod>  
<ns1:Prod xmlns:ns1="uri">  
  <ns1:ProductID>317</ns1:ProductID>  
  <ns1:Name>LL Crankarm</ns1:Name>  
  <ns1:Color>Black</ns1:Color>  
</ns1:Prod>
```

e a minha consulta foi:

```
    select *
from tabela
where [campo_xml].value('(/Prod//ProductID//node())[1]', 'int') = 316
```

e não retornou nada, alguém tem idéia do que está faltando?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu descobri como é:

é só colocar `*:<nome do elemento>`, assim filtra por qualquer namespace, tem como 'apelidar' o namespace, mas para o meu caso era só filtrar pelo elemento mesmo.